# SQL Server cursor very slow updating per row with stored procedure inside

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2014, database-cursor

I have a problem, when updating 50k records it takes 30 - 45 minutes to finish. But when I update 10k records it takes only 2-3 minutes.

How can I possibly fix this issue? Is there a way to improve its execution without changing the `Exec ICS_GetPrincipalInterest`?

Here is my SQL code, already tried using `while` statements but it's much slower.

```
CREATE TABLE #getPI
(
    BranchCodeValue VARCHAR(10), 
    AccountNumberValue VARCHAR(50), 
    PrincipalReturnValue MONEY,
    InterestReturnValue MONEY, 
    ServiceFeeReturnValue MONEY, 
    PCLIReturnValue MONEY, 
    PDInterestReturnValue MONEY, 
    PDPenaltyReturnValue MONEY, 
    MRIReturnValue MONEY, 
    DSTReturnValue MONEY, 
    DefInterestReturnValue MONEY, 
    OtherChargesReturnValue MONEY, 
    ODROCRReturnValue MONEY 
) 


SELECT TOP (50000) 
    BranchCode, AccountNumber 
INTO 
    #tempLoans 
FROM
    Loans801.dbo.LoanAccount 
WHERE
    (LoanStatus NOT LIKE '%clos%' 
     AND LoanStatus NOT LIKE '%write%') 
ORDER BY 
    dategranted DESC

DECLARE @getBR VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @getACCNT VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @setCutOffDate VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 

DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR; 

BEGIN 
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT Branchcode, accountnumber 
        FROM #tempLoans       

    OPEN @MyCursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @getBR, @getACCNT 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO #getPI 
            EXEC ICS_GetPrincipalInterest @getBR, @getACCNT, @setCutOffDate 

        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @getBR, @getACCNT 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor; 
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor; 
END; 

DROP TABLE #tempLoans 

SELECT * FROM #getPI 

DROP TABLE #getPI
```

Thanks in advance! Please help me :)

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: @Shawn, Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) sir

Comment: And what does `ICS_GetPrincipalInterest` do? More often than not, a cursor isn't the most efficient way to get at the data you want. And what are the possible values that can be in `LoanStatus`? Do you need to use a `LIKE` to get those values, or are there a bunch of common values? But the biggest question really being about the sproc. It can very likely be done without the cursor.

Comment: @Shawn, its computes daily interest,charges, and more per record, loanstatus has atleast 5 types of status.

Comment: Right, but can the calculations be done directly within the query to the data? Is a sproc needed? It might need to be redesigned. My guess would be that the slowness you're seeing would be from both the fact that you're using a cursor to do some row-based calculations and something inside the cursor that's running inefficiently.  Also, if you have 50K+ records with only about 5 `LoanStaus` values, then you probably should normalize that column and throw a good index on it. The index alone would probably speed it up tremendously.

Comment: best option is to redesigned the stored procedure but the down side is it will take much more time, the SP contains thousand lines of code, more testing to comply. this update is rush, thats why i am looking for alternative. Noted, I'll try indexing

Comment: If there are thousands of lines of code to calculate daily interest charges, than it may be doing a lot more than it should, and that could easily cause it to take 30+ minutes to complete. Unfortunately, "rush" is all to often the bane of any developer (and future developers dealing with the code). But it is what it is. Good indexing on any fields involved in this process will make a huge improvement. But I'd still say refactoring away from the cursor will likely be a massive improvement, too.

Comment: your are right sir, thanks. i ll try refactoring the code, but im still open if there is still alternative way to do it.

Comment: Try the indexes first. But I'd definitely keep that block of code high on the list of things to take a look at.

Comment: Also, can "clos" and "write" be in the middle of your `LoanStatus` string? And again, if they are only a small handful of possible values, be more specific. `LIKE '%clos%'` will be much slower than `LIKE 'close%'` which will also be slower than `= 'closed'` or `= 'account closed'`, or whatever. Again, look at the values in `LoanStatus` and see if they can be normalized.